# How to use google cloud load balance with cloudflare DNS proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've a domain with cloudflare nameservers.

I used google cloud buckets + google cloud load balancers for my static react app.

I first tried to use the app with Cloudflare DNS proxy off, and almost everything was fine.

Now I tried to use the app with DNS proxy on for protection, and I'm getting a error Too Many redirects.

This what I see in my chrome network tab.
[image: Chrome network tab]

I also face the same error on 404 page(even if cloudflare proxy is turned off).

Comment: Details on the configuration of Cloudflare, load balancer, and DNS settings are needed to help you. In general, I do not recommend putting Cloudfare in front of Google Cloud load balancers. What benefit do you expect from the configuration headaches?

Comment: Note: your redirection loop can be caused by your code not correctly detecting how the client connected (http vs https). That is an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting my SSL encryption mode to full

Comment: When asked questions in comments, take the time to answer them. Your question does not show the original configurations. Your answer does not provide details on why this works so that future readers can understand the original problem and solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).